# Identityserver 4 Consent page not showing

Tags: identityserver4

I have managed to get Identity Server 4 up to the point where I need to grant the app my consent so to speak but the consent page wont show. This is what I get

```
This localhost page can’t be found No webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:44361/consent?returnUrl=%2Fconnect%2Fauthorize%2Fconsent%3Fresponse_type%3Did_token%2520token%26client_id%3Dangular2client%26redirect_uri%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A44380%26scope%3Dopenid%2520email%2520profile%2520securedfilesscope%2520resourcescope%26nonce%3DN0.46395672677896951497118418043%26state%3D14971184180430.1487668170892953
```

Below is he Consent Controller with the index method that is suppose to called to return the consent view or page. It appears like the controller is not being hit at all let alone call the index method

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ConsentController : Controller
{
    // GET: api/values
    private readonly ILogger<ConsentController> _logger;
    private readonly IClientStore _clientStore;
    private readonly IResourceStore _resourceStore;
    private readonly IIdentityServerInteractionService _interaction;

    public ConsentController(
        ILogger<ConsentController> logger,
        IIdentityServerInteractionService interaction,
        IClientStore clientStore,
        IResourceStore resourceStore)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _interaction = interaction;
        _clientStore = clientStore;
        _resourceStore = resourceStore;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Shows the consent screen
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="returnUrl"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string returnUrl)
    {
        var vm = await BuildViewModelAsync(returnUrl);
        if (vm != null)
        {
            return View("Index", vm);
        }

        return View("Error");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it worked but this is what happened.  I removed this `[Route("api/[controller]")]` from the Consent Controller and the consents page showed up

Comment: Why it worked is because somewhere the consent page is defined as being available at `https://localhost:44361/consent` but your consent controller was saying it was available at `https://localhost:44361/api/consent`.

Comment: Ahh! thanks a lot. Wondering where this is occurring